# Woocommerce custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

As you can see, the title, the placeholder image, the six bottles
image at the top are rendered by the single-product template. I need
it to be rendered by bto-item.php file so that I can edit the CSS, the
contents of it through the template files.

Can you give me the steps to work like that? Currently the select
options are being executed by the Composite product plugin templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your currently used template create new folder named woocommerce and in it put the single product php file. And modify it by your need. :)

Comment: It's already created elibyy. Any other alternative solution? :)

Comment: If you are familiar with php you will notice the calls for images and title etc I'll be near pc soon I'll post example lines

Comment: OK. Just managed to do this. But how to call the do_action from composite plugin templates? Thanks

Comment: i didn't get your other question, and i'm glad you figured it out and if i helped mark my answer as correct

Comment: Can you help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061962/woocommerce-hidden-buttons-and-add-to-cart-problems