# Woocommerce hidden buttons and add to cart problems

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce composite plugin installed in my site.

The quantity button and add to cart buttons are hidden from the front end but I can see them getting executed through Firebug.

After clicking on [add-to-cart button](http://www.burgerbar.dk/product/the-wine-company-smagekasse/?add-to-cart=1279), it gives me the following error:

> The configuration you have selected cannot be added to the cart. The quantity of "Vin #1" must be between 1 and 1.

How to solve this?

Comment: a. You've got an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in/home/buradmin/public_html/wp-content/themes/flaske/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/bto-cart-button.php on line 121.  b. I need some code to help you out

Comment: Thanks bro! I already fixed it :)

Comment: Okay. Will be happy to help on any problem

Comment: Anything you can help with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166873/mailchimp-form-file-edit